# How do I evaluate the sum $\sum_{n=1,3,5,...}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{4}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, summation, harmonic-numbers

I'm trying to evaluate the following sum:

> $\frac{480\hbar^{2}}{\pi^{4}ma^{2}} \cdot \sum_{n=1,3,5,...}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{4}}$

I've written out a couple partial sums for $n_{odd}$ up to $7$ : $1 + \frac{1}{81} + \frac{1}{625} + \frac{1}{2401}$ but am a bit lost as to where to go to actually evaluate this. I've looked online for the formula for the harmonic series and figured I would just try to parse the sum of the odd terms then raise that to the $4^{th}$ power... or do the same with the odd terms of $\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ and square them but I can't seem to find them or make any headway. Any help is much appreciated.

The solution is:

> $\frac{5\hbar^{2}}{ma^{2}}$

Which tells me that the answer to my sum of odd numbered terms for $\frac{1}{n^{4}}$ must be $\frac{\pi^{4}}{96}$ but I still don't know how we got there. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletLambdaFunction.html $\lambda (4) = \frac{\pi^4}{96}$, for which there exist many proofs that $\zeta (4) = \frac{\pi^4}{90}$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof of $\sum_{n=1,3,5,\ldots}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^4}=\frac{\pi^4}{96}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013336/proof-of-sum-n-1-3-5-ldots-infty-frac1n4-frac-pi496) – found quickly [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%2C3%2C5%2C...%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%5E%7B4%7D%7D%24)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define Riemann zeta function as

$$
\zeta(s)=\sum_{n\ge1}{1\over n^s}
$$

Then we have

\begin{aligned}
\sum_{\substack{n\ge1\\n\text{ odd}}}{1\over n^s}
&=\sum_{n\ge1}{1\over n^s}-\sum_{\substack{n\ge1\\n\text{ even}}}{1\over n^s} \\
&=\zeta(s)-\sum_{n\ge1}{1\over(2n)^s} \\
&=(1-2^{-s})\zeta(s)
\end{aligned}

This indicates that

\begin{aligned}
\frac{480\hbar^{2}}{\pi^{4}ma^{2}} \cdot \sum_{n=1,3,5,...}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{4}}
&=\frac{480\hbar^{2}}{\pi^{4}ma^{2}}{15\over16}\zeta(4) \\
&={450\hbar^2\over\pi^4ma^2}\zeta(4)
\end{aligned}

Finally, using the fact that $\zeta(4)={\pi^4\over90}$, we conclude

$$
\frac{480\hbar^{2}}{\pi^{4}ma^{2}} \cdot \sum_{n=1,3,5,...}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{4}}={5\hbar^2\over ma^2}
$$

Comment: typo in the middle? should be $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(2n)^s}$

Comment: @peek-a-boo Edited. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

Another method is by using Fourier coefficients of the function $f$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ defined by
$$
f(x) = |x| 
$$
Then using integration by parts and using Fourier coefficient definition, one can obtain
$$
\hat{f}(0) = \frac{\pi}{2} 
$$
and for $n \neq 0$,
$$
\hat{f}(n) = \begin{cases} 
      0 & \text{ if $n$ is even} \\
      \frac{-2}{n^2\pi} & \text{ if $n$ is odd} \\
   \end{cases}
$$
Now, the famous Parseval's identity (which relates function with it's Fourier coefficients) states that if $f \in L^2([-\pi,\pi])$, then

$$
\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}|\hat{f}(n)|^2 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)|^2dx
$$
For our case, we can write

$$
|\hat{f}(0)|^2 +  \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}}|\hat{f}(n)|^2 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}x^2dx 
$$
Thus,
$$
\frac{\pi^2}{4} + \sum_{n = \pm 1, \pm 2,...}\frac{4}{n^4\pi^2} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{2\pi^3}{3} = \frac{\pi^2}{3}
$$
which implies
$$
\frac{4}{\pi^2} \cdot 2 \sum_{n=1,3,...}\frac{1}{n^4} = \frac{\pi^2}{12}
$$
and hence
$$
\sum_{n=1,3,...}\frac{1}{n^4} = \frac{\pi^2}{12}\cdot \frac{\pi^2}{8} = \frac{\pi^4}{96}
$$

And hopefully you can use it in your computation.